# Authorize.net send silent post for first transaction?

Tags: payment-gateway, subscription, authorize.net

Does Authorize.net send a Silent Post with a subscriptions first payment information?

The initial response I get when I create the subscription via the API is a few things pretty much telling me it was successful, however the silent post sends a lot more information about the actual payments. I'm wondering if it will send that for the first payment of the subscription as well as each month or just for each month?

If it does send the silent post for the first payment, and I set the current day as the start date, is that processed at a certain time that day or shortly after the subscription was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they do.

Sorry, from everywhere I read people told me that in sandbox mode they didn't send silent post, so I thought I had to figure it out myself, actually though they do send it in sandbox mode, and I received a silent post for all of my first payments.